# Classification of line bundles over surfaces

Tags: smooth-manifolds, line-bundles, 4-manifolds

I'm currently trying to understand the blow-up process for 4-manifolds. A step in this journey is to understand, topologically, what happens when you pluck out a 4-ball and replace it with $\mathbb{CP}^2$ (minus a 4-ball). The tautological bundle is defined as $$\tau=\lbrace (l,p):p\in l\in \mathbb{CP}^1\rbrace$$ whose complex line bundle structure is given by the first projection map $\pi_1:\tau\to\mathbb{CP}^1$. Shouldn't we be including the pairs $(l,(0,0))$? Because, for example, if we pull back $l=[0:1]$ by $\pi_1$, we obtain $\lbrace ([0:1],(0,y)):y\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace\rbrace$ which is just $\mathbb{C}$ minus a point. It feels like we need to put the origin back if we want a complex line bundle. So, **my first question is**: Is this correct? Do we need to add $(0,0)$ to each fiber?

**My second question** is more general. If $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ and $S$ is a closed orientable surface, then how do we know how many $\mathbb{F}$ bundle structures there are on $S$? There is a proof I've seen recently which shows that $\mathbb{CP}^2-\lbrace P\rbrace\cong \tau$ and the last line is "since the self-intersection of the 0-section is $-1$, these are the same complex line bundles and thus are diffeomorphic."

What results does this conclusion lean on? It seems to imply that complex line bundle structures on the sphere are classified by some integer. I'd like to know what that classification is.

Comment: Complex line bundles over compact connected oriented real surfaces are classified by Chern class, equivalently, by Euler number .

Comment: So $\tau$ does contain the origin of each fibre. Otherwise it would not be a line bundle, but rather the principal $\mathbb{C}^\times$-bundle associated with one (in this case the Hopf fibring).